# Bluetooth sending but not receiving

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I want to connect my mobile to a Bluetooth module associated to an Arduino, send data, receive a result and then close the connection.

There are two possible behaviors:

**1. Behavior**

The application gets started and the mobile connects to the module. When I press the button, data get sent to my module. The Arduino processes the incoming data and sends a result back via the same connection. Furthermore, the console spits out that data have been sent and received by my mobile.

The data connection works just like I want but the connection should be established as I press the button and not beforehand.

**2. Behavior**

The application gets started without the mobile getting connected to the module.
As soon as the button gets pressed, the connection will be established (not beforehand!) and data will be sent.
I know that this data is being received by the Arduino, because I print incoming data into the modules console.
Confusingly the result is not being received by my mobile.

**Question**
Why does this error of data not being received back only arise if I don't establish a connection beforehand but as soon as the button is pressed.

Code:

Connect

```
public static void connect ( BluetoothDevice device ) {

    try {

        if ( Bluetooth.hasAdapter() ) {

            if ( Bluetooth.adapter.isEnabled() ) {

                Bluetooth.connected = device;

                Bluetooth.socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( device.getUuids()[ 0 ].getUuid() );
                Bluetooth.socket.connect();

            }

        }

    } catch ( Exception exception ) {

        exception.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

1. Behavior ( send and receive data )

   ```
   Bluetooth.connect( device );

   Button button = ( ( Button ) this.findViewById( R.id.activate ) );
   button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener () {

       @Override
       public void onClick ( View view ) {

           Bluetooth.send( "#activate" );

       }

   } );
   ```
2. Behavior ( send but not receive data )

   ```
   Button button = ( ( Button ) this.findViewById( R.id.activate ) );
   button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener () {

       @Override
       public void onClick ( View view ) {

           Bluetooth.connect( device );
           Bluetooth.send( "#activate" );

       }

   } );
   ```

~Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Problem is now solved.
It was just my fault.

When I was reading from the BluetoothSocket, an exception occured in the second case.
For some unknown reason I have not printed the exception but broke out of the while loop. This meant that no more data could have been collected.

***Problem:*** 
I started the Collector before I actually opened up the BluetoothSocket. Unfortunately the Collector then started to read from a closed Socket which led to an exception. I didn't realize this because I wasn't printing the error message which doesn't happen to me normally.

Comment: 2 questions. 1.Where are you reading the data back received from arduino. 2. Can you add some delay(around 2 seconds) in Case 2 between   Bluetooth.connect( device ); and Bluetooth.send( "#activate" ); and let us know does it work as you expected ?

Comment: 1. I've created a new thread that is reading out of the BluetoothSocket's InputStream. After reading the result will be printed into the console. That is the reason why sending and receiving works in the first case. It should also work for the second case but it doesn't.

Comment: Add delay between connect and send like [this](https://pastebin.com/5fRaMvsm) and let us know the result. Also check the logs for any error's between the two behaviour's

Comment: 2. I also tried executing the code for sending data later (1s,2s,5s,20s) but nothing does work. The thing is that it already sends data if I don't use a delay but it just doesn't collect data back.

Comment: Is the method of receiving data and reading data from arduino same in both behaviour's?. Also when are intializing this read functionality after connecting before connecting ? Or after sending only ?
It is little difficult to debug since the code you posted doesn't have the read functions.